# Change due date for production order in SAP B1 with the DI SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I am trying to change/update the due date of a production order in SAP B1 with the code below:

```
public static void ChangeDueDateForProductionOrder(SAPB1Credentials credentials, int poAbsEntry, DateTime dueDate)
{
    DebugLogger.Log(credentials.CompanyDB, $"Changing due date for production order '{poAbsEntry}' to '{dueDate.ToString(C_DATE_FORMAT_NL)}'.");

    using (var sap = new SAPB1Connection(credentials))
    {
        ProductionOrders productionOrder = sap.Company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oProductionOrders);

        if(productionOrder.GetByKey(poAbsEntry))
        {
            productionOrder.DueDate = dueDate;

            if (productionOrder.Update() != 0)
            {
                var message = $"Error while changing due date for '{poAbsEntry}' to '{dueDate.ToString(C_DATE_FORMAT_NL)}', the following error is given '{sap.Company.GetLastErrorDescription()}'.";
                DebugLogger.Log(credentials.CompanyDB, message);
                throw new Exception(message);
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception($"PoId '{poAbsEntry}' does not exists.");
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Error while changing due date for '145' to '11-09-2016', the following error is given 'Field cannot be updated (ODBC -1029)'.

And the error SAP gives is:

> Field cannot be updated (ODBC -1029)

Additional information:

- It is a new production order that has the status `Planned`.
- Creation date is `Today`.
- Due date I am trying to change it to is `Today + 5 days`.
- The Id (AbsEntry) for the production order is `145`.
- SAP Business One 9.1
- Yes, I can alter the due date in the SAP B1 GUI without problems.

**Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example**

The code below gives me the exact same error. Replaced connection settings with `??`.

```
using System;
using SAPbobsCOM; // Reference to SAP B1 DI SDK (32-bit)

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credentials = new SAPB1Credentials
            {
                Server = "??",
                CompanyDB = "??",
                Username = "??",
                Password = "??"
            };

            SAPbobsCOM.Company sap = new SAPbobsCOM.Company();
            sap.Server = credentials.Server;
            sap.DbServerType = credentials.ServerType;
            sap.CompanyDB = credentials.CompanyDB;
            sap.UserName = credentials.Username;
            sap.Password = credentials.Password;
            sap.language = credentials.Language;
            sap.UseTrusted = credentials.UseTrusted;

            var returnCode = sap.Connect();

            if (returnCode != 0)
            {
                var error = sap.GetLastErrorDescription();
                throw new Exception(error);
            }

            ProductionOrders productionOrder = sap.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oProductionOrders);

            if (productionOrder.GetByKey(145))
            {
                productionOrder.DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

                if (productionOrder.Update() != 0)
                {
                    var error = sap.GetLastErrorDescription();
                    throw new Exception(error);
                }
            }
            else
                throw new Exception($"PoId does not exists.");
        }

        public class SAPB1Credentials
        {
            public string Server { get; set; }
            public string CompanyDB { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public BoSuppLangs Language { get; set; } = BoSuppLangs.ln_English;
            public BoDataServerTypes ServerType { get; set; } = BoDataServerTypes.dst_MSSQL2008;
            public bool UseTrusted { get; set; } = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing, and why do I get this error?

Comment: I reached to (http://scn.sap.com/thread/3954409), I will update this post when I have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked SAP thread in the comment.

Edy Simon said:

> Hi Lars,
>
> Must be a Patch Level bug.
>
> I can use your code to update it on SBO 881PL6.
>
> You might want to test it on another version.
>
> Regards
>
> Edy

Which resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for commenting the response that was aimed towards me.